# Minimize rational function on interval

Tags: sequences-and-series, dynamical-systems

Define a sequence $(f_n)$ of rational functions by
$f_1(x)=2,f_2(x)=x$ and

$$
f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{f_{n-1}(x)}+\frac{1}{f_{n-2}(x)}
$$

Let $I$ be the interval $I=[\frac{7}{6},\frac{3}{2}]$. Then

**Fact.** For $n\in [2,15]$, the minimum for $f_n$ on 
$I$ is attained on the boundary of $I$, i.e. at some
$b_n\in \lbrace \frac{7}{6},\frac{3}{2} \rbrace$.

Can anyone prove or disprove my conjecture that this holds for any $n\geq 2$ ?

My thoughts : assuming the conjecture is true,
denote the case where $b_n=\frac{7}{6}$ by $a$ and
the case where $b_n=\frac{3}{2}$ by $b$, for $n=2$ to $n=30$, we 
have the following sequence :

$$abbabbaabaabaabbabbaabaabaabb$$

This sequence does not seem to follow any particular pattern.

Related : [Proof of a limit for a recursively-defined sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890531/proof-of-a-limit-for-a-recursively-defined-sequence)

Comment: It looks like any $f_n$ is monotonous on interval $I=[\frac{7}{6},\frac{3}{2}]$. Could it be another conjecture (or part of yours ?) ? Thus your characterization by the bound $a$ or $b$ of $I$ in which the max is obtained could be expressed as the sign of $f '_n$ on I.  A convincing fact in favour of the truth of the conjecture is as follows : consider differetiating the defining relationship : this gives $f '_n(x)= - f '_{n-1}/ f_{n-1}^2 -  f '_{n-2}/ f_{n-2}^2 $ ; out of that, one can conclude that if $f '_{n-2}$ and $f '_{n-1}$ have the same sign, $$f '_n$ will have an opposite sign [...]

Comment: [ctd] This would account for the fact that behind a sequence $aa$ (resp $bb$) you have necessarily $b$ (resp $a$). But is it true that every $f_n$ is monotonous ?...